# Ecto.Multi - insert two related records

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am trying to insert two related records. When I try to create a new user. I would like to first create a record in the `pools` table and pass its' id to the `users' table` pool_id`. I am trying to use Ecto.Multi, but without any success. I would appreciate a guidance or any help! Thanks in advance! I have never used Ecto.Multi, hence, I would be grateful for the explanation. Errors at the end.

Here is my user schema:

```
  schema "users" do
    field :email, :string
    field :full_name, :string
    field :password_digest, :string
    belongs_to :role, EmployeeRewardApp.Role
    has_one :pool, EmployeeRewardApp.Points.Pool
    timestamps()
    # Virtual Fields
    field :password, :string, virtual: true
    field :password_confirmation, :string, virtual: true
  end

  @doc false
  def changeset(user, attrs) do
    user
    |> cast(attrs, [:full_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :role_id])
    |> validate_required([:full_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :role_id])
    |> cast_assoc(:pool)
end
```

Pool schema:

```
  schema "pools" do
    field :starting_points, :integer
    field :used_points, :integer
    belongs_to :user, EmployeeRewardApp.Accounts.User
    timestamps()
  end

  @doc false
  def changeset(pool, attrs) do
    pool
    |> cast(attrs, [:starting_points, :used_points])
    |> validate_required([:starting_points])
  end
```

And create function:

```
  def create(conn, %{"user" => user_params}) do
    alias Ecto.Multi
    Multi.new
    |> Multi.insert(:pool, %Pool{starting_points: 50, used_points: 0})
    |> Multi.merge(fn %{pool: pool} ->
      user_pool_relation_multi(pool.id, conn, %{"user" => user_params})
    end)
    |> Repo.transaction()
  end

  def user_pool_relation_multi(pool_id, conn, %{"user" => user_params}) do
    alias Ecto.Multi
    Multi.new
    |> Multi.insert(:user, User.changeset(%User{}, user_params))
    |> Repo.transaction()
  end
```

The error is now:

```
[error] #PID<0.1477.0> running EmployeeRewardAppWeb.Endpoint (connection #PID<0.1476.0>, stream id 1) terminated
Server: localhost:4000 (http)
Request: POST /users
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42703 (undefined_column) column "user_id" of relation "pools" does not exist

    query: INSERT INTO "pools" ("starting_points","user_id","inserted_at","updated_at") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4) RETURNING "id"
        (ecto_sql 3.6.2) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:760: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.raise_sql_call_error/1
        (ecto 3.6.2) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:725: Ecto.Repo.Schema.apply/4
        (ecto 3.6.2) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:350: anonymous fn/15 in Ecto.Repo.Schema.do_insert/4
        (ecto 3.6.2) lib/ecto/association.ex:814: Ecto.Association.Has.on_repo_change/5
        (ecto 3.6.2) lib/ecto/association.ex:554: Ecto.Association.on_repo_change/7
        (elixir 1.12.2) lib/enum.ex:2385: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
        (ecto 3.6.2) lib/ecto/association.ex:532: Ecto.Association.on_repo_change/4
        (ecto 3.6.2) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:873: Ecto.Repo.Schema.process_children/5
        (ecto 3.6.2) lib/ecto/multi.ex:716: Ecto.Multi.apply_operation/5
        (elixir 1.12.2) lib/enum.ex:2385: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
        (ecto 3.6.2) lib/ecto/multi.ex:690: anonymous fn/5 in Ecto.Multi.apply_operations/5
        (ecto_sql 3.6.2) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:1017: anonymous fn/3 in Ecto.Adapters.SQL.checkout_or_transaction/4
        (db_connection 2.4.0) lib/db_connection.ex:844: DBConnection.transaction/3
        (ecto 3.6.2) lib/ecto/repo/transaction.ex:20: Ecto.Repo.Transaction.transaction/4
        (ecto 3.6.2) lib/ecto/multi.ex:696: Ecto.Multi.apply_operation/5
        (elixir 1.12.2) lib/enum.ex:2385: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
        (ecto 3.6.2) lib/ecto/multi.ex:690: anonymous fn/5 in Ecto.Multi.apply_operations/5
        (ecto_sql 3.6.2) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:1017: anonymous fn/3 in Ecto.Adapters.SQL.checkout_or_transaction/4
        (db_connection 2.4.0) lib/db_connection.ex:1512: DBConnection.run_transaction/4
        (ecto 3.6.2) lib/ecto/repo/transaction.ex:20: Ecto.Repo.Transaction.transaction/4
```

Also, When I change `starting_points: 50` to `"starting_points" => pool.starting_points` (so it is set from the form) it says:

```
key "starting_points" not found
```

Params:

```
user     %{"email" => "test.999@test.com", "full_name" => "Test Test", "password" => "Test", "password_confirmation" => "Test", "pool" => %{"starting_points" => "80"}, "role_id" => "1"}
```

As you can see in the schemas. I have table pools with stating_points and used_points, and users table with users' info and pool_id field. What I want to do is:  When creating new user, insert new record to pools table with value of starting_points given in the form and used_points set to 0. Then insert other params into users table with newly created id in pools table. The error says that pool_id is not in pools table. This error and Ecto.Multi make me confused on how to create new user while also setting their starting points in pools table.

CreatePoolsMigration

```
  def change do
    create table(:pools) do
      add :starting_points, :integer
      add :used_points, :integer

      timestamps()
    end
  end
```

CreateUsers

```
  def change do
    create table(:users) do
      add :full_name, :string
      add :email, :string
      add :password_digest, :string

      timestamps()
    end

  end
```

AddPoolIDToUsers

```
  def change do
    alter table(:users) do
      add :pool_id, references(:pools)
    end
    create index(:users, [:pool_id])
  end
```

Comment: I guess it should be `pools` and not `pool` and you are not creating `belongs_to :user` relation once you insert to pool because there is no user, I suggest you create a user first then insert into `pools`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. pools doesn't work either. I think I have to insert pool first, because I need to insert pool_id into users table.

Comment: which of those lines is line 41?

Comment: `ERROR 42703 (undefined_column) column "user_id" of relation "pools" does not exist` is that a true statement in the error message? This answer would be improved if you just removed the first error message and put the corrected line in the example, since you solved that problem.

Comment: Hey @Segfault, please see UPDATE 2 section. I will also explain one more time what I want to achieve with Ecto.Multi but I'm confused... Insert new record to `pools` table with value of `starting_points` from the form and `used_points` set to 0. Then insert other params into `users` table with newly created `id` in `pools` table.

Comment: what line is this about?: `unknown field \`:pool_id\` in %EmployeeRewardApp.Points.Pool{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:built, "pools">, id: nil, ...}`? I don't see the code that caused this in your question, but what this error message is telling you is that you've tried to access a field named `pool_id` on a %Pool struct, but it doesn't have that field. You need to use `id` instead in that line. This question needs to be cleaned up a bit before it can be answered. Narrow it to just one problem that can be reproduced in a different project for best results.

Comment: @Segfault Okay, I cleaned up a bit my question. I have been tweaking code in the meanwhile and got another error. I'll stop with those changes for now since it causes mess in the question.

Comment: `(Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42703 (undefined_column) column "user_id" of relation "pools" does not exist` You will need a migration to add the user_id column to the pools table, according to this error message.

Comment: Can you share your migrations?  It would be helpful to confirm what your database tables actually look like.

Comment: @Everett Sure, I just updated my question with migrations code. However, my guess is that there is something wrong with my Ecto.Multi code because I don't understand it in 100%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you have added a `pool_id` column to the users table. Now the error message you're facing is that a `user_id` column does not exist on the pools table.

Ecto believes that you have a `user_id` column in the pools table because of this line in your schema `belongs_to :user, EmployeeRewardApp.Accounts.User`.

the difference between `belongs_to` and `has_one` is that the `belongs_to` relationship goes into the schema which holds the foreign key (aka user_id in this case). Check this section of the [Ecto docs on Hexdocs.pm](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/2.2.11/associations.html#adding-associations). This seems like the correct direction for this relationship, so use a migration to remove pool_id from the users table and add user_id to the pools table.

Alternatively you could flip this around in the schema, and put that a user belongs_to a pool and that a pool has one user, but I think you'll find this is the unconventional way to relate the tables. Best advice is to stick with convention when possible, especially when learning new technologies.

With this strategy, you won't even need to use a Multi to insert the pool record, because you already have the ID number of the user, you can just insert one row into the pools table, instead of inserting a pool row and then getting the ID of that row and updating the users table.

Comment: I think, I will go with the first of your solution ideas. Can you give me a hint, how do I create new user and their record in pools table without using Ecto.Multi now?

Comment: oh, if it's a new user then you want to use the Multi like you've been doing, just do the user insert first and pass the user id to the pool insert.

Comment: Yeah, so right now I am in the same place I was when I was asking this question. Right now I have something like: `    alias Ecto.Multi

    Multi.new()
    |> Multi.insert(:user, User.changeset(%User{}, user_params)
    |> Multi.insert(:pool, fn %{user: %User{id: user_id}} ->
      Pool.changeset(%Pool{user_id: user_id, starting_points: 50, used_points: 0})
    end))
    |> Repo.transaction()` but I return error: `no function clause matching in Ecto.Multi.add_operation/3` And another problem I have is to pass starting_points from the form to this code.

Comment: it's a different problem, so better off in a different question.

Comment: Please, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68818313/problem-creating-user-and-insert-user-id-in-associated-table. I am trying to do this without Ecto.Multi but I am open to Ecto.Multi.