# Problem creating user and insert user_id in associated table

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am trying to insert user details into users table, and then user_id, starting_points and used_points to pools table. I was checking with IO.inspect and it gets to line `if user_changeset.valid? do`. After this line it goes straight to  `render(conn, "new.html", changeset: user_changeset, roles: roles)`. Can someone help me (best with explanation) how to achieve that? I attach controller, schemas and form code.

User controller

```
plug :scrub_params, "user" when action in [:create]
def new(conn, _params) do
    roles = Repo.all(Role)
    changeset = User.changeset(%User{pool: %Pool{}}, _params)
    render conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset
  end

  def create(conn, %{"user" => user_params}) do
        roles = Repo.all(Role)
        pool_changeset = Pool.changeset(%Pool{}, user_params["pool"])
        user_changeset = User.changeset(%User{pool: pool_changeset}, user_params)
        if user_changeset.valid? do              
          Repo.transaction fn ->
            user = Repo.insert!(user_changeset)
            pool = Ecto.Model.build(user, :pool)
            Repo.insert!(pool)
          end
          |> put_flash(:info, "User created successfully.")
          |> redirect(to: Routes.user_path(conn, :index))
        else
          render(conn, "new.html", changeset: user_changeset, roles: roles)
        end
      end
```

I was also trying with Ecto.Multi but like the first method, it "does nothing" - no error, but also not creating any record, just like "refresh" the page.

```
  def create(conn, %{"user" => user_params}) do
    roles = Repo.all(Role)
    changeset = User.changeset(%User{}, user_params)
    alias Ecto.Multi

    Multi.new()
    |> Multi.insert(:user, User.changeset(%User{}, user_params))
    |> Multi.insert(:pool, fn %{user: %User{id: user_id}} -> Pool.changeset(%Pool{user_id: user_id, starting_points: 50, used_points: 0}) end)
    |> Repo.transaction()
    render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset, roles: roles)
  end
```

Schemas

```
  schema "pools" do
    field :starting_points, :integer
    field :used_points, :integer
    belongs_to :user, EmployeeRewardApp.Accounts.User
    timestamps()
  end

  @doc false
  def changeset(pool, attrs) do
    pool
    |> cast(attrs, [:starting_points, :used_points, :user_id])
    |> validate_required([:starting_points, :user_id])
  end


  schema "users" do
    field :email, :string
    field :full_name, :string
    field :password_digest, :string
    belongs_to :role, EmployeeRewardApp.Role
    has_one :pool, EmployeeRewardApp.Points.Pool
    timestamps()
    # Virtual Fields
    field :password, :string, virtual: true
    field :password_confirmation, :string, virtual: true
  end

  @doc false
  def changeset(user, attrs) do
    user
    |> cast(attrs, [:full_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :role_id])
    |> validate_required([:full_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :role_id])
    |> cast_assoc(:pool)
    |> hash_password
  end
```

Form

```
<%= form_for @changeset, @action, fn f -> %>
  <%= if @changeset.action do %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      <p>Oops, something went wrong! Please check the errors below.</p>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= label f, :full_name %>
  <%= text_input f, :full_name %>
  <%= error_tag f, :full_name %>

  <%= label f, :email %>
  <%= text_input f, :email %>
  <%= error_tag f, :email %>

  <%= label f, :password, "Password", class: "control-label" %>
  <%= password_input f, :password, class: "form-control" %>
  <%= error_tag f, :password %>
  
  <%= label f, :password_confirmation, "Password Confirmation", class: "control-label" %>
  <%= password_input f, :password_confirmation, class: "form-control" %>
  <%= error_tag f, :password_confirmation %>

  <%= label f, :role_id, "Role", class: "control-label" %>
  <%= select f, :role_id, roles_for_select(@roles), class: "form-control" %>
  <%= error_tag f, :role_id %>

  <%= inputs_for f, :pool, fn i -> %>
    <%= label i, :starting_points, "Starting pool", class: "control-label" %>
    <%= number_input i, :starting_points, class: "form-control" %>
    <%= error_tag i, :starting_points %>
    <%= hidden_input i, :used_points, value: 0, class: "form-control" %>
  <% end %>

  <div>
    <%= submit "Save" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: if the changeset is not valid, then check the errors on it to see why it is not valid. probably it didn't want you to include the pool in the user changeset. You need to create the user independent of any pool, then when you create the pool supply the user_id. It will be related correctly.

Comment: How do I check errors on changeset if they are not displaying in the browser or terminal?

Comment: There is a an `errors` field in the changeset struct you can inspect: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#module-the-ecto-changeset-struct

Comment: Hmm, I removed :used_points and :user_id from validate_required in pool changeset and everything works now but I don't know if it's okay to remove that...